# parse word document

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

The word documents I want to parse will have a known format, defined by a word template. Users will use the word template to create the document. I need to parse data, including values from drop downs, from the word document using C#. This will be done on a SharePoint 2010 server. What is the recommended way to do this? I've seen people mention Open XML SDK 2.0; should I use that? If so, do I need to convert the .docx to XML, then parse it? In some cases, I will also have to write to the Word document, how should this be done?

Preferably a solution will support Word 2010 and 2007 but if tools for 2010 are significantly better I'd like to know that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Since we are talking about Sharepoint I would simple use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office or as yourself suggest the Open XML SDK.  If you want to support both 2010 and 2007 I would attempt to avoid 2010 features keep compatibility possible between the two versions.

Comment: @ramhound One of my areas of confusion is that a Word .docx is not or does not seem like an XML document. How can it be used as one by Open XML..? Links or terms to research on that?  Thanks... appreciate your reply.

Comment: Note to anyone reading, Visual Studio Tools for Office uses the Word Object Model (for the Word portion of the office tools)... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157892.aspx

Comment: @KyleM: It's XML, but it's zipped up to save space. Try changing the file extension to .zip and open it up.

Answer (score 1):

The file extension for Office Open XML is .docx. The .docx file can be described as an archive of several different files. Files that handle what fonts, styles, objects will exist in the word document. Those files itself will be describe as XML.